# useEffect React Hook: detecting the change of a property for each object in an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

StackOverflow,

I'm having a question about [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), more particularly, `useEffect` hook. I'm aware that one use case of `useEffect` hook is to capture changes of certain state variables.

Let's suppose we have the following code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [sv, setSv] = useState([
    {
      a: 1,
      b: { c: 'val11', d: 'val12', e: 'val13' }
    },
    {
      a: 8,
      b: { c: 'val21', d: 'val22', e: 'val23' }
    },
    {
      a: 19,
      b: { c: 'val31', d: 'val32', e: 'val33' }
    }
  ]);

  const someCallback = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('change triggered!')
  });

  useEffect(someCallback, [sv]);
}
```

Let's also assume `sv` is an array of objects, each of which has the same set of keys, but different values associated with these keys.

It works just fine if I want to execute `someCallback` on **any** changes made to `sv`, including objects nested in each object contained by the array `sv`.

Now let's assume that there is a need to execute `someCallback` only when certain properties of each object in the array `sv` will change. For example, I'll want to only monitor changes to `b.c` and `b.d`. The way I thought would work is:

```
useEffect(someCallback, [sv.map(item => item.b.c), sv.map(item => item.b.d)]);
```

However, it didn't trigger at all. This probably because `Array.map` [creates a new array with no reference to the previous one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), however, I can't think of any other way to map the necessary values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you spread the mapped arrays that should actually work. `useEffect(someCallback, [...sv.map(item => item.b.c), ...sv.map(item => item.b.d)]);`

Comment: Maybe you can keep the previous state, check if the parts of the objects you wanted to change are changed in the new state. do that inside the useEffect (compare between new and previous state). that's a messy way but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think using  **SPREAD** operator should work

```
useEffect(someCallback, [...sv.map(item => item.b.c), ...sv.map(item => item.b.d)]);
```

Comment: Getting an error: `The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant. Previous: [] Incoming: [[object Object]]`