# useEffect Hook - how to detect the change of an object's property in a state array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

How  can `useEffect` detect the change in an array's object's property 
**without knowing the `state` array size** because items may be added dynamically

- in this particular case the "price" property in one of the objects
  **The array is a `state`**

**Just for example if changing the price property** `useEffect` won't invoke, price will be the same next time (after - `localStorage.getItem`)
(In my app I change it dynamically in a different way this is for example).

```js
  const checkUseEffectLocalS = () => {     
    array[0]['Price'] = '12';    
    setItemsArray(array);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => checkUseEffectLocalS()}>
        Check
        </button>
    </>
  );
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(userItems, JSON.stringify(array));
  }, [array.map((item) => item.price)]); //Tried this way also but it didn't worked
```

**Niether**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(userItems, JSON.stringify(array));
  }, [array]);  // won't work
```

**The array structure**

```js
   array([
      {
        id: 1,
        productName: 'Vitamin',
        price: '10$',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        productName: 'Powder',
        price: '26$',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        productName: 'Multivitamin',
        price: '17.5$', 
      },
    ]);
```

Before asking I checked very similar question but with no real answer - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67886755/useeffect-react-hook-detecting-the-change-of-a-property-for-each-object-in-an-a)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to handle the state change ?

Comment: @AlwaniAnis Yes sure

Answer (score 4):

Without using *useEffect*

```js
const checkUseEffectLocalS = () => {   
let arr= [...array]
    arr[0]['Price'] = '12';    
  localStorage.setItem(userItems, JSON.stringify(arr))
    setItemsArray(prev=>arr);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => checkUseEffectLocalS()}>
        Check
        </button>
    </>
  )
```

By using *useEffect*

```js
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(userItems, JSON.stringify(array))
}, [JSON.stringify(array)])
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way with `useEffect` ? because I don't think I wanna use `localStorage.setItem` twice, each in a different component. It will get complicated I think

Comment: Yes I will edit my answer to add the other way.

Comment: You can look at my previous question to **see how I change the property** -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743359/why-can-t-conditional-operator-be-used-to-conditionally-increment-property-like?noredirect=1#comment121489245_68743359

Comment: I think my answer works very well with your situation, to handle objects change you should convert it to json string , that is it.